# How to filter an array of strings based on their index in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I have an array of weekdays, [Mon, Tue, Wed..Sun]. I also have another array with the indexes of the selected weekdays. For example if the latter array contains [0,2,4] I would like to create a new selectedWeekdays array with [Mon, Wed, Fri] and send it forward to another component (in React).

What would be the best way (ES6 if possible) to filter out the selected weekdays of the original array?

Comment: map indices with values ...?

Comment: Use the `filter()` method along with `includes()` to filter out the selected weekdays from the original array using ES6 syntax. Like: `weekdays.filter((weekday, index) => selectedIndexes.includes(index));`

Answer (score 3):

In `map()` way:

```js
const weekDays = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];
const selectedWeekDays = [0,2,4];

const newSelectedWeekDays = selectedWeekDays.map( i => weekDays[i]);

console.log(newSelectedWeekDays);
```

In `filter` way:

```js
const weekDays = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];
const selectedWeekDays = [0,2,4];

const newSelectedWeekDays = weekDays.filter((v, i) => selectedWeekDays.includes(i));

console.log(newSelectedWeekDays);
```

Comment: Thank you, this must be the best and simplest way!